# How to pass a String argument so it becomes part of a class method call?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how to pass the string arguments in the convert_and_multiply method into the findViewById method, so that the string becomes part of the method call, and no longer a String. For example I would like to pass the argument "fruit_1_price" such that it becomes findViewById(R.id.fruit_1_price);

I was reading about "reflection" in Java, but I could not fully understand it, and whether it applied to my situation. I also tried using String wildcards and place holders, but I cannot understand how to make a String, not a String anymore.

Thank you for any help.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double fruit_1_total = convert_and_multiply("fruit_1_price", "fruit_1_spinner");//, fruit_2_total, fruit_3_total;

            Toast.makeText(c, Double.toString(fruit_1_total),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public double convert_and_multiply(String v, String s) {
           TextView price = findViewById(R.id.v);
           Spinner amount = findViewById(R.id.s);
           Double total = Double.valueOf(amount.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

          return total;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this is a more complex answer than I was anticipating though, and I realize @nupadhyaya's answer is what I actually wanted to do. When I try your solution I get "Cannot resolve method 'getPackageName()". Android Studio has no suggestions for package imports for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to complicate it? Pass the id directly to the convert_and_multiply 
 function :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double fruit_1_total = convert_and_multiply(R.id.v, R.id.s);//, fruit_2_total, fruit_3_total;

            Toast.makeText(c, Double.toString(fruit_1_total),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public double convert_and_multiply(int priceId, int amtId) {
           TextView price = findViewById(priceId);
           Spinner amount = findViewById(amtId);
           Double total = Double.valueOf(amount.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

          return total;
        }
```

Comment: Its a smell to constantly do findViewById like that.  Its something you should do just once, when the views are created, and store the value somewhere.Passing in the views, or something that maps names to views would be better.

Comment: True! But i don't know what @Joe P 's intentions were so i gave a solution as per his code

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't catch on that the R.id's are ints. I had even tried object! Ugh. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Accepting this a correct answer because after more thought this is what I was actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to this code :

```
public double convert_and_multiply(String v, String s) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    int id1 = res.getIdentifier(v, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
    TextView price = findViewById(id1);

    int id2 = res.getIdentifier(s, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
    Spinner amount = findViewById(id2);

    Double total = Double.valueOf(amount.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Where do you put your code? is it an activity class or a view class?
If you put at activity, then you can simply replace your code from `getContext().getPackageName()` to `getPackageName()`